# Push HTML to the view with variable AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I push HTML within the Angular variable?

controler.js

```
function myControler($scope){

   $scope.myItem = '<p>' + Test + '</p>';
}
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="myControler">{{myItem}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the directive ngBindHtml

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])

.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

More infornation on ngBindHtml: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Or you can create a custom directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc:example-example83@snapshot?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you shouldn't.

It's the view's responsibility to generate HTML. The controller should expose structured data to the view, through the scope. It shouldn't generate HTML.

If that's really not an option, then use the ng-bind-html directive and the [`$sce`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce) service. The example code shows exactly what you want to do.